# transforming a texture from one object to another

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, topology

I have a scanned object with the topology of tries and its unwrapping is with "islands" but once it's in a 3d software the texture fits perfectly well. I need the object to be retopologies with quads so i can change its unwrapping to a one piece unwrap. is there a way to tranfer the original texture to the retopologied object with the texture getting all messed up?
would appreciate any advice.

Thank you...

btw- I did try the CTRL+L option - not what I was thinking about.
Are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If your new model is in quads and is the same size, sits in the same place as the original then you should be able to bake the texture from the original to the new model as long as you unnwrap your new model and set up a texture to bake to that is high enough resolution to accommodate the pixels of the original texture. You would use the 'bake selected from active' option in the render panel bake tab.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Craig ! Did try your suggestion, but it did not work. I might have missed something... could you please elaborate more about the process ?

Comment: I'll try to work up an example, but in the mean time you could just look up 'baking textures from selected to active' and find information including videos on youtube and the like.